# How to solve this logistic regression problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Q.1 `Run the code in the below cell to load the iris data from sklearn dataset

The features are the dimensions of flowers petals belonging to iris species
The target names are the species to which the flower belongs.They are mapped as 0,1 and 2.
In this excercise you will perform logistic regression predict the species of flow given the petal dimensions as features
To view the data by printing iris_X and iris_Y (Optional).`

ANS1 -

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
iris_X = iris.data
iris_y = iris.target
print(iris.feature_names)
print(iris.target_names)
```

Q2 -
import train_test_split function from sklearn.model_selection
split the data into train and test set with test_size = 0.33 and random_state = 101

ANS 2-

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(iris_X,iris_y,test_size=0.33,random_state=101)
```

Q3 -
import LogisticRegression from sklearn
initialise logistic regression model and assign to variable 'model'
fit the model with train data(X_train and y_train)

ANS 3-

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model = LogisticRegression()
#fit the model
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Q4 -
using the model predict the output of test data

ANS 4 -

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Q5 -
import classification_report from sklearn
pass y_test and y_pred to classification_report().
print the output of classification_report

ANS 5 -

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
dd=classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
print(dd)
```

```
output -   precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00        15
           1       1.00      0.95      0.98        22
           2       0.93      1.00      0.96        13

    accuracy                           0.98        50
   macro avg       0.98      0.98      0.98        50
weighted avg       0.98      0.98      0.98        50
```

Q6-
from classification report record the values of precision and recall
assign the values of precision and recall to variable 'precision' and 'recall' in the below cell

ANS 6 -

```
precision = 0.98
recall = 0.98
###End code(approx 2 lines)
with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
  text_file.write("precision= %f\n" % precision)
  text_file.write("recall= %f" % recall)
```

There are questions and then there are the steps i wrote below them to answer the questions. Yet when i complete all questions and answers i am unable to complete the hands on challenge.
It shows - " Please complete all the tasks" .
All the above steps gets compiled in Jupiter notebook.

Is there anything i am doing wrong ?
Is there anything missing?

Comment: we can't reproduce this problem. It's rather best to contact whoever prepared the questions to resolve the issue instead

Comment: I just wanted to know whether i missed some code or not . If all the answers i wrote are correct , then its the problem(bug) of the online platform on which i am submitting my answers.

Comment: May be there be a cell you've not executed yet? (judging from "Please complete all the tasks")

Comment: i double checked everything , i think there might be something missing from the code.

Comment: Perhaps the required answers for Q6 need all the precision and recall values?  Something like, `dd=classification_report(y_test, y_pred, output_dict=True);precision=[dd[my_key]['precision'] for my_key in dd.keys() if type(dd[my_key])==dict]`, etc.

Comment: looks like the output is expecting a real number and not list.